# HIghcharts Legend

Tags: highcharts, legend

Is there a way for me to display legends in highcharts just by creating name and its color as a separate data?

If this is my data:

```
[{
  "x": 0.92,
  "y": 1.12,
  "date": "05-18-2003",
  "color": "#0082c8",
  "idNo": 3,
  "mc": "green",
  "symbol": "circle"
},
{
  "x": 0.92,
  "y": 1.13,
  "date": "05-18-2003",
  "color": "#0082c8",
  "idNo": 10,
  "mc": "green",
  "symbol": "circle"
},
{
  "x": 0.96,
  "y": 1.05,
  "date": "06-10-2003",
  "color": "#f58231",
  "idNo": 3,
  "mc": "green",
  "symbol": "circle"
},
{
  "x": 0.96,
  "y": 1.09,
  "date": "06-11-2003",
  "color": "#911eb4",
  "idNo": 3,
  "mc": "green",
  "symbol": "circle"
},
{
  "x": 0.96,
  "y": 1.1,
  "date": "06-11-2003",
  "color": "#911eb4",
  "idNo": 10,
  "mc": "green",
  "symbol": "circle"
}
]
```

and the legend data that I created dynamically based on the above data is
legendData=

```
[{name: "05-18-2003", color1: "#0082c8"}
{name: "06-11-2003", color1: "#f58231"}
{name: "06-10-2003", color1: "#911eb4"}]
```

How can I make legend from this legendData variable?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what is between default legend and you want to create from legendData.

Comment: Because of the way I am sending data to the highcharts API, I am not able to get the legend the way I wanted. The legend name should the date and the color is its corresponding color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To modify legend item labels you can use `labelFormatter` function. As for the different color for each legend item, you can use styled mode and style them using CSS. Take a look at the example posted below.

DOCS Reference:
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.labelFormatter

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/mw06ywvp/